# TextBox value onchange Add new column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've the following ImageUpload text box field in my MVC view.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBox("file", new { type = "file", @class = "form-control" })
}
```

Now, when a user select an image, I want to add one more column that displays the path of the image.

I tried the following code but doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function ()
 {
 $("#file").on("input", function ()
  { // trigger when you input to textbox
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
            {
              <td>
                 @{
                     @Html.DisplayFor(m => imagePath)
                  }
              </td>
           }
         }
       }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested sample, this displays name of the file in new column, for security reasons browser will not have access file path details so you won't be able to show the path(at least that's what I am aware of feel free attach a link if you find something)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @*Second parameter is the value field for texbox which is missing in oyur code*@
                    @Html.TextBox("file", i, new { @type = "file", @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(".form-control").on("change", function (event) {
        var fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
        $(this).parent().append('<td>' + fileName + '</td');
    });
</script>
```

quoting [Sam Axe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74015/sam-axe)
"JavaScript runs in the browser and you cause changes on screen by manipulating the DOM.
Razor runs on the server and executes code, or transforms code (usually into text such as HTML)." So if you write Razor code for displaying the new column it will not work because that is rendered on server side.